# Hard disk files can only be read in linux

Tags: file, system

I tried deleting a folder(about 2gig) from a portable hard disk/drive in windows unsuccessfully, i then removed the hard disk and connected to a Fedora 14 environment and deleted it successfully. Now when i connect the same hard disk to a windows machine i can't see the files. however everything appears in linux, what should i do to fix this?

Comment: please provide an example of the name of a file you can't delete?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the hard drive is in the wrong format. It depends on the version of windows you are running, but all the latest windows needs an NTFS hard drive. If you are connecting it as an external then it will also work with the FAT format as well.

Do you know what format the hard drive is in? I need a little bit more information, like what are you trying to do with the drive and how are you connecting it?

Comment: i'm guessing it was on one of those two formats(FAT/NTFS) since it was working fine as an external/portable hard drive.  i know fedora runs ext 3/4 but why should it automatically change the file system of the hard drive. i a am running a dual boot system and always access my windows stuff from fedora.(same hard disk/ different partitions) and never have this problem.